# Stack (LinkedList) implementation save big data from backend

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I have created a stack with O(1) operation in my case I have implemented a linked list within my push remove operation.

But I am a bit confused how I can save a big amount of data for example if I get it from the backend, eg.

> const response = [{data:1, data2:2, data3:3}, {{data:1, data2:2,
>   data3:3}]

```
class Node{
  constructor(data, next = null){
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
  }
}

class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
  }

push(item) {
  let newNode = new Node(item, this.head );
   this.head = newNode;
}

pop() {
    if(!this.head){
      return;
   }

    this.head = this.head.next;
}

}
```

Now I want to pass my response to my stack like this:

```
const stack = new Stack();
stack.push(resp
```

onse);

Here I am passing entire response into one node. This is confusing to me. 
Would I say I need a way to push each property or object inside my response? 
or If I loop again over my array then it cost time again?.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the data will be coming in as an array of plain JavaScript objects. If you want the behavior of your `Stack` class, you're going to have to add them to your structure individually.

Comment: Seems you're looking for `for (const obj of response) stack.push(obj)`. And yes of course, converting an array to your custom stack type will cost linear time.